# cabal new-sdist includes test files as well

Tags: haskell, cabal, sdist

I want to create an sdist package for my Haskell project.
For simplicity let's assume the following project structure:

```
/ root
  | src
    | MyLib.hs
  | test
    | MyLibTest.hs
  | Changelog.md
  | MyProject.cabal
  | LICENSE
```

There are two targets defined in the cabal file

```
library
  exposed-modules:    MyLib
  hs-source-dirs:     src
  -- ...

test-suite: MyProject-test
  type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:     test
  main-is:            MyLibTest.hs
  -- ...
```

When I execute `cabal new-sdist --list-only` I get the following list:

```
./changelog.md
./MyProject.cabal
./LICENSE
./src/MyLib.hs
./test/MyLibTest.hs
```

My question: is it ok to include the test-related files in the sdist package or shall I remove them (if so - how)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you try to generate a library-only sdist, you get this error:

```hs
$ cabal new-sdist --list-only <library-name>
cabal: The component library cannot be packaged for distribution on its own.
Only entire packages may be packaged for distribution.
```

So I'd say it's recommended to upload the whole thing.

Hackage does let you preview a library before publishing it, using package candidates. I'd say [upload your source tarball](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/candidates/upload) as a package candidate, and double check your tests don't show up.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'll give it a go later today.